# Getting parser error from wikipedia in my discord bot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

The code I am trying to use is below. This is my discord bot using the rewrite of `discord.py`

```
@client.command()
async def wiki(self, ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(f'Searching for {arg}.')
    print(wikipedia.summary(arg))
    await ctx.send({arg})
```

However, I am getting an error every time I try to run this I am getting this error:

```
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py:389: 
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser
 for this system ("lxml"
```

This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on **line 389** of the file 
`/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py`.

To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument `'features="lxml"'` to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

```
lis = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('li')
```

I have tried editing *bs4* and changing

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin)
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin, 'html.parser')
```

But I have still not gotten it to work, would it be better to ask GitHub on the `discord.py` page?

I have no clue Any help would be appreciated.

edit:

I have changed my code around and it appears to work great, however, I read that using requests in discord.py is not a good idea because it stops your bot and could stop it and cause a restart. Is it possible to do this without a request?

```
@client.command()
async def wiki(self, ctx, *, arg):
    input = arg
    print(wikipedia.page(input).url)
    await ctx.send(f'<{wikipedia.page(input).url}>')
    await ctx.send(wikipedia.summary(input, chars=500))
```

Above is my new code and it works perfectly as intended. I just want to make sure I'm not going to somehow break my bot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with discord.py, but rather [an issue with the wikipedia library](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues/107).
However, [it should already be fixed](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/commit/50bc236836dc20546af61ea7ca6198c3f039a816) in the lastest development version of wikipedia.

You're right in that the wikipedia library uses requests, and requests is [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean).

> Is it possible to do this without a request?

You're using the HTTP request to get the information from Wikipedia, so no.
You'll want to consider using an asynchronous library instead or performing the requests to the Wikipedia API yourself, using an asynchronous library such as aiohttp.